# C++ Derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, derived

I have a class (Queue) which inherits from a class named Stack.
it goes like this:

```
template <class T> class Stack
{
         public:
                virtual const T pop();
                 LinkedList<T> lst;
};

template <class T> class Queue : public Stack<T>
{
         public:
                virtual const T pop();
};

template <class T> const T Queue<T>::pop()
{
                             const T val = lst[0];
                             return val;
}
```

The compiler says "lst undecleared"...why?

Comment: Also, unless you do this as an exercise (or perhaps homework), you are strongly advised to use `std::stack` and `std::queue` from the standard library. If you don't like those standard classes because of the separate `top` and `pop` member functions, I suggest you read about exception safety (providing a `pop` function alone is never enough).

Comment: How a `queue` *is-a* `stack`? Reconsider the inheritance relationship, it probably does not make that much sense for your use case.

Answer (score 5):

Because `lst` is a member of the base class `Stack<T>` which is a dependent type on `T`. The compiler can't check dependent types until the template is fully instantiated. You have to let the compiler know that `lst` is part of such base class by writing `Stack<T>::lst`.

As its mention in comments, `this->lst` is also a viable solution. However, people are likely to remove the `this` as seen unnecessary. `Stack<T>::lst` seems more explicit in this way.

Comment: So that means, that for every data member which is dependent on T, I'm supposed to write Stack<T>::name ?

Comment: K-ballo: Or `this->lst`. @TaruStolovich: Or `this->name`. Or `Queue<T>::name`

Comment: I've most often seen the `this->lst` solution and not the solution that uses the scope operator.

Comment: `this->lst` is also a viable solution, but people are most likely to remove it as unnecessary opposed to `base::lst`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `this->lst` instead of `lst`.